# How to load google maps in jquery colorbox?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, colorbox

Is it possible to load google maps in jquery color box without iframe. If not possible can anyone provide a working link where map is loaded using iframe.. 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use gmap3 - jquery plugin for google maps? [http://gmap3.net](http://gmap3.net/en/pages/5-getting-started/#jquery-features-16)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I have a specific need of displaying map in a popup(colorbox is prefered).
Seems like gmap not fulfilling that!

Comment: Can you not call gmap from within your code loading your jquery colorbox?

Comment: That may work.. But if we can implement directly(without using an additional plugin) it will be better. right Tom?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: [Load google maps dynamically](https://developers.google.com/loader/#Dynamic) and the callback section of [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

Comment: Got it working using a similiar approach after going through 
[link](http://www.primecut.gr/2011/06/colorbox-with-google-maps/)
Thanks for the help